# Overlapping scrollviews block touch events

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, touch-event

needs some advice on how to achieve an effect in Appcelerator Titanium.  I need to create an effect that has two scrollviews, on top of each other both that receives touch events.

Seems that under iOS and Android native programming you can tell the OS not to gobble up the touch events.

I need a kind of see-through effect with both layers receiving the touch events? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question after messing around...

One scroll view, composite layout of child elements, dynamically fix position of child elements you want other elements to scroll over (making sure you either add them in order or dynamically change z-order) which still retains the interactivity of the elements within the scroll view.

Check this link, This will be helpful: [`https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html`](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)